# Can I use AVAudioRecorder with an external mic?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, avaudiorecorder

Sorry if this question is obvious or duplicated. My 30 minutes of research led me nowhere.

We have an iPhone app that live streams video from the device to our remote Wowza servers. 
We're looking to integrate the Swivl (motion tracking tripod) into our product, and it uses a wireless microphone that feeds into the 30-pin port of our iPhone. Swivl's SDK doesn't include anything about capturing audio from their hardware so I assume that it would be handled by the iPhone itself.

If I use the AVAudioRecorer, will it automatically route the audio input from the 30-pin port instead of the default microphone, or do I have to explicitly define the audio source?

Any clues help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few tests, it seems that iOS automatically routes incoming audio signals. 
There is no need to explicitly specify the source of the audio.

Comment: I should note that the audio automatically worked in 3/4 apps tested. It's possible that a different audio framework does not support external mic's.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from AVAudioRecorder documentation:

In iOS, the audio being recorded comes from the device connected by the user—built-in microphone or headset microphone, for example. In OS X, the audio comes from the system’s default audio input device as set by a user in System Preferences.

Comment: Thanks, but I've seen this. Does this imply that the input device is automatically managed by the system? I'm looking to find out if I have to manually configure the input, or if I can just implement AVAudioRecorder and depend on operating system magic to route the signals.

Comment: Also, providing audio input through the 30-pin is not as customary as through the 3mm jack so that throws me off a little as well.

Comment: Nothing in the `settings` dictionary includes input source options.